# mess up ownerships after cli action

Tags: magento2, permissions, cli, grunt, setup-upgrade

so I am running a magento 2.2.4 in development and one in production, the dev is ok and I can do all, the production is an exact copy of it on apache 2.4 and Ubuntu 16.04, every time I use any kind of cli command (grunt, setup, whatever ) to regenerate the static file I got a blank page and to put all in place again I have to run chown -R www-data:www-data /.

I am sure the cli user belongs to the www.data group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My workaround is to set www-data as primary your user group.

> sudo usermod -g www-data yourusername

It will cause all of the files will be in www-data group by default. But keep it in mind, even those you wouldn't like to share in this group.

Comment: already tried this and it does not work, which is strange

Comment: I actually tried this again lately and it solved the problem, maybe I had a typo before so this is the answer to the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the user that you are using to run the command, but based on your information it's not www-data.

I suggest you run the command always as www-data.

```
sudo su -u www-data <command>
```

This will make sure you are always running the command as www-data.

Comment: I actually do this, but this is not a solution, mostly cause most of the process is autmated and not executed manually, so the only solution would be to write a single bash, but still I would like to solve the problem and use no hack

Comment: check if Magento cronjob is running as www-data